# Regional Value format mismatch in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a oracle database developer form India and working with European client. For both side we are using SQL Developer(same version) for query building.
In Europe, they used to write numeric value like: `amount = 5,6`
But in India, we used to write it like: amount= `5.6`
SQL developer also supports this value as per regional basis.
So, the challenge is when We write query for sum(amount), It works fine from our side, but failed in European side and also vice-versa. This is one kind of scenario, but some other value format challenges are also there.

Europe:

```
Select Sum(amount) from Account;
**Output:** 234,567
```

India:

```
Select Sum(Amount) from Account;
**output:** ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
```

**So, can anyone suggest how we can overcome this situation. As I am working with European client, I want to adapt European value format supporting SQL Developer.**

I tried to install the same link from where my client installed, but its not worked.

Comment: `ORA-00909` is not about formatting, but a function call. Maybe there's some `sum` function created in the schema that has more than one argument? Please, check: select `select * from all_source where name = 'SUM'`

Answer (score 2):

> In Europe, they used to write numeric value like: amount = `5,6` But in India, we used to write it like: amount= `5.6` SQL developer also supports this value as per regional basis.

Alter your session so that you have the same settings as the client. For example, if you want to have all the defaults (numeric separator characters, default date format, etc.) as someone in France then use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'France';
```

This will change: the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting to `,` ; the default string-to-date (and vice versa) format to `DD/MM/RR`; and the currency to Euros.

You can see the complete list of settings using:

```sql
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;
```

If you only want to change the numeric characters then just change that one setting:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', ';
```

---

As for your second issue:

> India:
>
> ```sql
> Select Sum(Amount) from Account;
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```error
> ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
> 00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
> ```

This is conflating two things. The `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting only affects the default **display** format and will not prevent you performing any calculations as the database will use the same binary format to store numbers independent of whether the client application used to connect to the database chooses to **display** the data in one format or another.

What you have appears to be a local function named `SUM` that is shadowing the built-in function and you are calling the local function and not the built-in function.

As commented by @astentx, you can check the data dictionary for such instances:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'SUM';
```

(However, I could not get a local function to be called in preference to the built-in aggregation function so could not replicate your error.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XCI7TvcH)

Comment: Thanks!! Some of the cases I have applied and its worked. If any procedure or function is getting called then we can use this alter command with execute immediate statement. But if I want to execute any views/tables independently through any job, this solution is difficult to implement there. Could you please help here.  
I was just thinking whether it possible to install Europe region DB setup in India. I am not able to get how this region setting works in SQL DB

Comment: @nodev_101 The best method is to write code that does not rely on the NLS settings and then you do not need to care what any user sets them to. Alternatively, you can write a logon trigger to set the NLS settings at the start of every session (but you should really fix the code not to rely on implicit conversions or formatting).